# Validator not workind in Adonis Resorceful route

Tags: adonis.js

I'm following the [docs](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/validator), and trying many things but without success validating `resource` routes. My code:

routes.js:

```
Route.resource('/user', 'UserController').validator(
  new Map([
    [['user.store'],[ 'UserStore']]
  ])
) .apiOnly();
```

app/Validators/UserStore.js:

```
class UserStore {
  get rules() {
    return {
      email: 'required|email|unique:users,email',
      password: 'required',
      name: 'required|min:30',
      tiago: 'required|min:30'
    };
  }

  get validateAll() {
    return true;
  }

  get messages() {
    return {
      'email.required': 'You must provide a email address.',
      'email.email': 'You must provide a valid email address.',
      'password.required': 'You must provide password.',
      'tiago.required': 'You must provide password.'
    };
  }
}

module.exports = UserStore;
```

The validation never happened this way.

If I change to an individual route, it validates, it works:

```
Route.post('/user', 'UserController.store').validator('UserStore'); //it works
```

But I want to use the `resource` to write less and have a clear code.

---

How can I use validator with resource routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustrating way to solve it...

Just removing `/` on route, and it worked:

```
Route.resource('user', 'UserController').validator(
  new Map([
    [['user.store'],[ 'UserStore']]
  ])
) .apiOnly();
```